# what is meant by Instance name?

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2005, netbeans

what is a *sql server instance* ? what does it mean and why do why need it ?

I needed here :

[image]

What does an instance name mean ?

Comment: Seems like you have two instances on that host: a default instance, and a named instance called SQLEXPRESS. So, if you want to connect to the default instance, you shouldn't put anything in the `Instance Name:` field. If you want to connect to SQL Express, then enter `SQLEXPRESS` there. [Some reference here](http://serverfault.com/questions/11746/what-is-a-sql-server-instance).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, its the name or unique connection string of your "instance" of the SQL Server.

When you install software you can create one or more instance of the dataset. Each instance and a different hostname and port which allows you to contact that instance.

Without it you can't contact the database.

Comment: when I run the command `SQLCMD -L` on the sql command prompt I get two under the heading _servers_  `ADARSH-PC`, `ADARSH-PC\SQLEXPRESS` what does that mean ?

Comment: Not sure. I know more about Java than Sql-Server. I would try googling those names to see if they have a common meaning.

Comment: the command is checking for the installed sql server instance

Comment: I would try putting it in the `Instance Name` field.